# is there any better tool and easy tool than selenium?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

is there any better tool and easy tool than selenium?

Comment: Better for what?  There aren't too many tools that are 'just like' selenium.

Comment: actually I am new in web development teting.I want to know how should i use a tool to test? I found selenium but I am not very comfortable with it.If you provide agood tutorial then also it will be good

Comment: The definition of "better and easy" varies individual to individual. My opinion is: Selenium is the better, because it is nice for web functional testing. And it supports many programming language such as Java, C#, python, perl etc.

Answer (score 3):

Selenium is used by the likes of Google, Ebay, Microsoft, Apple so its a good tool and is easy enough to use.

I have a number of [tutorials](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/selenium_training.htm) on my site that should get you going.

Answer (score 2):

**WebTest:**
[WebTest Key Characteristics](http://webtest.canoo.com/webtest/manual/keyCharacteristics.html)
[Selenium Webtest](http://mguillem.wordpress.com/2007/10/29/webtest-vs-selenium-webtest-wins-13-5/)

**WebDriver:**
 [Introducing Webdriver](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2009/05/introducing-webdriver.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sahi, http://sahi.co.in would be the simpler better alternative. Automatic Waits, No XPaths, excellent handling of AJAX and dynamic ids, simple robust APIs would be some of the areas where Sahi is better. Disclaimer: we wrote Sahi.

Comment: As I know it needs to use Sahi Script for using Sahi. Is there any other language support for using Sahi rather than sahi script?

Comment: There are Java and Ruby drivers too. http://sahi.co.in/w/java http://sahi.co.in/w/ruby

Comment: Thanks Narayan Raman. Is there PHP driver for Sahi?

Answer (score 0):

In general Selenium is a pretty good tool, but it  does have a learning curve (Most things do). Once you get used to it it is prety easy to use.